# Does AutoMapper support Open Generics and Inheritance at the same time?

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I can see that AutoMapper supports [Open Generics](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Open-Generics) and [Inheritance](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance) but I can't get it to work with a combination of the two.

Given

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Bar<T> : Foo
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

and assuming complementary classes of `FooDto` and `BarDto<T> : FooDto` then the following line throws an Invalid Cast Exception saying it can't convert from `FooDto` to `BarDto<EntityDto>`

```
Mapper.Map<Bar<Entity>, BarDto<EntityDto>>(AMethodWhichReturnsABar<Entity>());
```

I have tried the following mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, EntityDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(Bar<>), typeof(BarDto<>));
```

and

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, EntityDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>()
    .Include(typeof(Bar<>), typeof(BarDto<>));
Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(Bar<>), typeof(BarDto<>));
```

both of which result in the InvalidCastException. The only thing that works is if I explicitly map the closed generic like so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, EntityDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Bar<Entity>, BarDto<EntityDto>>()
```

This is fine but it means I will have to add a mapping for every closed generic combination I might have.

Is this functionality something AutoMapper offers and I'm just doing it wrong? Or am I stuck adding a mapping for every combination of T I need to use?

Comment: First make it work without generics, then add them back in and see what you get.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/eb1a445b373acfac3895e9fd308c43e070db546e/src/UnitTests/MappingInheritance/ShouldSupportOnlyDestinationTypeBeingDerived.cs) are some As examples.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu If I remove the generics and make the Value property an Entity and EntityDto then it works with either of the two mappings I tried originally. Adding T back in results in the same error.

Comment: Probably that's a bug, but As works.

Comment: Are you able to give an example of how you think using As would solve the above? Interestingly if I remove the Foo to FooDto map then the open generic works. Unfortunately I do need that Foo/FooDto map but I think it might be solvable using As.

Comment: Did you follow that link? :)

Comment: Yes thanks. Nothing there _quite_ matches the above situation but even trying examples which are similar (i.e. Mapping `FooDto` to `BarDto<>` or mapping `Foo` to `FooDto` As `BarDto<>`) doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It works for me. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: :EmbarrasedFace: It works absolutely fine, even without As, if you're not using version 4.0.4 of AutoMapper.....

Comment: Yes, I didn't use As either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154519/discussion-between-thudbutt-and-lucian-bargaoanu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is yes. Rather embarrassingly the reason I couldn't is because I was testing using AutoMapper 4.0.4. Using 6.1.1 allows you to do the following and works as expected:

```
MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>     
{       
    c.CreateMap<Entity, EntityDto>();
    c.CreateMap(typeof(Foo), typeof(FooDto));
    c.CreateMap(typeof(Bar<>), typeof(BarDto<>));;  
});

config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();    
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

BarDto<EntityDto> result = mapper.Map<Bar<Entity>, BarDto<EntityDto>>(AMethodWhichReturnsABar<Entity>());
```

I've left my question and answered as, originally when I was looking, I couldn't see anywhere that explicitly stated that what I was asking was supported.